# MySQL - Having problems with COUNT() in query with GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql

I have a pretty big query which is used by an ajax call to return and also sort active items. From my understanding sub queries should be avoided where possible and since this query will be called very often, I would like to do just that.

At the moment everything is fine except for the `COUNT(b.bic) AS bids`. If there are two(2) bids the query returns four(4), if there are 4, it returns 8, and so on. I've tried grouping by other columns ... but no luck.

Some of the tables. I hope each of the column names are pretty self explanatory:

countries_ship - each item can be shipped to multiple countries so item_id can be duplicate.

```
id  item_id country_id  ship_cost
```

countries

```
id  country_code    country_name
```

item_expire - not sure if item_expire should have it's own table.

```
id  item_id exp_date
```

bids - Just as countries_ship, item_id can be duplicate. This is where the bids are stored.

```
id  item_id  user_id  bid previous_bid  bid_date
```

The query:

```
$q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("
SELECT c.ship_cost, 
 c.item_id, 
 co.country_name, 
 co.id AS co_id,
 i.id, 
 i.user_id, 
 i.item_start, 
 i.item_title, 
 i.item_number, 
 i.item_year, 
 i.item_publisher, 
 i.item_condition, 
 i.item_description, 
 i.item_location, 
 e.exp_date AS exp_date, 
 i.active, 
 CAST(u.fb_id AS CHAR(50)) AS fb_id, 
 u.user_pic, 
 MAX(b.bid) AS maxbid, 
 COUNT(b.bid) AS bids, 
 p.publisher_name, 
 t.tag_name
FROM countries_ship c
JOIN items i
 ON c.item_id = i.id
JOIN item_expire e
 ON c.item_id = e.item_id
JOIN users u
 ON i.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN bids b
 ON i.id = b.item_id
LEFT JOIN publishers p
 ON i.item_publisher = p.id
LEFT JOIN tags_rel tr
 ON c.item_id = tr.item_id
JOIN tags t
 ON t.id = tr.tag_id
LEFT JOIN countries co
 ON i.item_location = co.id
WHERE ".$where."
GROUP BY c.item_id ORDER BY ".$order." ".$limit."");
```

Comment: When using aggregate functions you have to group by all selected columns. In mysql it is not necessary but then results are "unpredictable". Best practise is join to select with agg function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try

`COUNT(distinct b.bic) AS bids`

This will ignore duplicates due to joins